# Top right corner bug? Missclick?

Tags: support, bug

Whenever I try to open the community tab to switch communities, like by going from gamedev to worldbuilding and vice versa.

I seem to maybe missclick something that I can't see or maybe it's just a bug, I try to click the community tab but it instantly opens the stack exchange site.  It only happens randomly, about 1 time out of 5.

[image]

[image]

Yes it happens on all devices.

Yes I'm pretty sure I'm hovering over the grey icon, not the blue icon.

More details:

It seems to happen as soon as I open a new page or go back to an idle page, it doesn't seem to happen to pages that I'm currently using.... I try missclicking on purpose and it doesn't send me to stackexchange. But this is only a theory.

I'm also using opera GX on the laptop and normal opera on mobile devices, no add-ons other blocking trackers.

Comment: Seems to happen to me only if I try to click and open that icon as a new tab (e.g., middle click)

Comment: @VLAZ might explain why it happens on laptop but then again, I don't use a mouse for my phones.

Comment: Update your browser. Did the same thing with mine until I updated it. Though it wasn't random, rather that every click did that. Your exact problem might be different.

Comment: Opera here, too. Have no idea what version, and I haven't updated it in forever. No issues with that icon at all. I tried ten times and it brought up a little list of subscribed forums each time.

Comment: This happens if you click before Javascript is loaded, which can happen a lot on really slow connections (or if you block js entirely).

Comment: I've flagged this post suggesting that it be migrated to [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). That's where you need to post issues that are problems with the service (e.g., software bugs). Individual Stack metas are for discussing policies of the Stacks. Posting this here is unlikely to draw the attention it needs to be evaluated and fixed. Cheers!